# List of video formats supported for playback in tvOS

Tags: video, playback, tvos

What video formats are supported for playback in tvOS?

I understand we can query [`audiovisualTypes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVURLAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/AVURLAsset/audiovisualTypes) and [`audiovisualMIMETypes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVURLAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/AVURLAsset/audiovisualMIMETypes) on the `AVURLAsset` class in tvOS to get a list of supported video types.

What is that list currently in tvOS 9.1?

Answer (score 1):

Not all the supported formats, but here's what's recommended, along with some DO's and DO NOT's.

https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/General/Reference/HLSAuthoringSpec/Requirements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016596-CH2-SW1

> All video MUST be encoded using AVC/H.264.
>
> Audio data SHOULD be provided as an elementary audio stream.
>
> Stereo audio formats are: AAC-LC. HE-AAC v1, and HE-ACC v2.
>
> Stereo audio MUST be provided.